# SQL--запрос из двух таблиц

Tags: sql

Есть таблица "product" и таблица "product_to_category"
связаны они полем id

Необходимо в таблице "product" в поле "name" найти строки, которые содержат "Дрель" и в таблице "product_to_category" в столбец "category" присвоить этим продуктам категорию "1240"

Подскажите как составить sql запрос? Я дошел до такого:

```
WHEN name LIKE '%дрель%' THEN UPDATE product_to_category SET category = 1240
```

Comment: Вы не выдумывайте синтаксис. а загляните в мануал для диалекта Вашей СУБД.

Comment: некий шаблон для вашего случая (один из возможных вариантов): UPDATE алиас SET колонка = значение FROM таблица1 алиас INNER JOIN таблица2 алиас2 ON алиас.id = алиас2.id AND алиас2.колонкасусловием LIKE значениепоиска